# How many solutions does $x$ have in $x^3 = \sigma^6$ in $S_{7}$

Tags: permutations, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles

> Let $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 1 & 4 & 6\end{pmatrix} \in S_{7}.$
>
> How many solutions does $x^3 = \sigma^6$ have?

Here is what I have done so far:

If we decompose $\sigma$ into disjoint cycles we get $\sigma = (1 2 3 5)(4 7 6)$. From this remark we deduce that $ord(\sigma) = lcm(3, 4) = 12$.

Since $ord(\sigma) = 12$, this implies that $ord(\sigma^6) = \dfrac{12}{gcd(12, 6)} = 2$, which results in $ord(x^3) = 2.$

Suppose $m = ord(x)$. We can calculate $m$ from this equation: $ord(x^3) = \dfrac{m}{gcd(m, 3)} = 2.$

That equation implies $m = \{2, 6\}$ and elements of order $2$ and $6$ indeed exist in $S_{7}.$

So basically what I understand from this is that we have an unknown permutation, $x$, which has the order of either $2$ or $6$ which is equal to a permutation of order $2.$

Does this mean that $x$ has $2$ solutions? Sorry if it's obvious but I barely grasp the concepts of modern algebra.

Comment: It's probably better to start by computing $ \sigma ^6 =  (13)(25)$ and then seeing how many cube roots that product of transpositions has.

Comment: @EthanBolker With the cube root of a permutation do you mean something like $\sigma^{-3}$?

Comment: I mean experiment to see what permutations satisfy $x^3 = (13)(25)$.